# why do i get this error? "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

Tags: php, laravel

I get this error on my website when I try to access a page

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: /home/goldhdfu/foresightonset.com.ng/resources/views/Admin/Coupon/index.blade.php)

and it brings 500 server error. enabling app debug in the .env file I got these other errors

> /home/goldhdfu/foresightonset.com.ng/app/Helpers/Helper.php

```
if (! function_exists('get_referral_by_bonus_by_id')) {

   function get_referral_by_bonus_by_id( $id )
   {
       $referral = User::find($id);
       
       $user = User::find($referral->referred_by_id);
       
       return $user->id;
   }
}

if (! function_exists('get_vendor_name')) {

   function get_vendor_name( $id )
   {
       $vendor = User::find($id);
       
       return $vendor->id;
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... `find` can return `null` if no record is found by that primary key

Comment: how to i check for possible record for that key?

Comment: can you show the part of the view the error is coming from

Comment: what version of Laravel and PHP are you using?

Comment: You cannot know in advance if the dataste exists, but you can provide a solution, if the result is null. E.g. throw an exception, give back an error message, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because `find` function is returning null for some of the records and you are trying to get the `id` from `null`. To tackle this you can `return` in this way.

```
//for the first function
 return !empty($user) ? $user->id : null;

//for the second function
 return !empty($vendor) ? $vendor->id : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

As @lagbox commented, the `User::find` returns `null` if no record is found, therefore we have different options, depending on your specific scenario:

1. Use `findOrFail`:

```
User::findOrFail($referral->referred_by_id);
```

2. Return `null` if the object is null:

```
if ($user == null) return null;
```

---

Full examples for both cases:

1.

```
if (! function_exists('get_referral_by_bonus_by_id')) {
   function get_referral_by_bonus_by_id( $id )
   {
       $referral = User::findOrFail($id);
       $user = User::findOrFail($referral->referred_by_id);
       return $user->id;
   }
}
if (! function_exists('get_vendor_name')) {
   function get_vendor_name( $id )
   {
       $vendor = User::findOrFail($id);
       return $vendor->id;
   }
}
```

2. 

```
if (! function_exists('get_referral_by_bonus_by_id')) {
   function get_referral_by_bonus_by_id( $id )
   {
       $referral = User::findOrFail($id);
       if ($referral == null) return null;
       $user = User::findOrFail($referral->referred_by_id);
       if ($user == null) return null;
       return $user->id;
   }
}
if (! function_exists('get_vendor_name')) {
   function get_vendor_name( $id )
   {
       $vendor = User::find($id);
       if ($vendor == null) return null;
       return $vendor->id;
   }
}
```

Comment: If user is null/empty, then `findOrFail()` will raise a 404 error and die.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! That might be the desired outcome based on the scenario. For that reason, I also included a second option to provide a different outcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (! function_exists('get_referral_by_bonus_by_id')) {

function get_referral_by_bonus_by_id( $id )
  {
   $referral = User::find($id);
   
   $user = User::find($referral->referred_by_id);
   if(isset($user))
    {
      return $user->id;
    }
    else
   {
      return '';
   }
   
 }
 }
```